# Why is it creating two vertices in the same spot?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

So im new but im going all out and trying to model a pistol and for some reason when im about to start beveling the edges, it messes up because there are two vertices located in the exact same point.  So I have to move one out of the way, then delete one, then create new faces.  Its very frustrating and I cant think of anything im doing wrong.  All I know is that it seems like it might be happening when I do a "loop cut" I think is what is called. (hitting ctrl+R)

edit: Ok now after playing around trying to see what the problem is, it got worse.  I didn't change any settings but now every time I try to move a vertices or an edge it just has multiple copies under it. I'm literally unable to do anything to the model without messing it up now.  Please help

Comment: Instead of deleting duplicated vertices one by one, select all of the vertices (A) then press Ctrl+V and select "remove doubles"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Blender, sometimes you can create faces or edges without knowing. For example, if you tried to extrude a face, (shortcut <kbd>E</kbd>), but then you canceled the operation with escape, you might not notice, but a new face have been created over the one you was selecting, and its now in the same position!. This might be how the problem that you have was started.

One solution might be in the Mesh> Cleanup> Degenerate Dissolve menu found in the 3D view header while in edit mode.